# Mostrar as mensagens no Console Inspecionar - Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Não consigo mais visualizar as respostas do meu VSCODE quando acesso o Inspecionar no Google Chrome. Até a pouco estava conseguindo ver todas as mensagem, mas depois que cliquei com o em 'Hide Messages from script.js" deixou de mostrar o resultado no meu Console. Já pesquisei de tudo e a box do HIDE NETWORK MESSAGES está ativo.[hide network messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Byn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você adicionou um filtro para ocultar as informações que vem deste arquivo, se olhar na parte superior do console, logo abaixo das abas Console, Sources, Network, tem um campo de "filtro".

Ao clicar em "Hide Messages from script.js", adicionou um filtro para ocultar tudo do caminho deste arquivo, que estará mais ou menos assim: `-url:file:///CAMINHO-DO-SEU-ARQUIVO`.

[image: campo-filtro-console]

É só apagar esse caminho, ou clicar no "X" na direita que remove o caminho do filtro. E pronto, irá parar de ignorar as respostas deste arquivo.  Espero ter ajudado.